How to set path for cmake
I am trying to build an openvino project security_barrier_camera_demo which is available in github https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree.
After cloning the openvinotoolkit repository in my Centos machine. I followed the commands available in the documentation to setup openvino https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/master/docs/dev/build_linux.md
But while performing the build by running build_demos.sh file. I am getting this error
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/share/cmake3
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.
Can someone please assist.
I also tried to install cmake from open source i.e. tar -zxvf cmake-X.Y.Z-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz  and set the path to CMAKE_ROOT but still got same issue.
Tried removing and reinstalling cmake from scratch.
I am using python version 3.10 and cmake version 3.30.
centos version: 7
GCC version: 4.8.5

Without any additional information, I'm inclined to accept CMake's self diagnosis: CMake is probably installed incorrectly.

You should remove the makefile and gnu-make tags from this question: it has nothing to do with makefiles or GNU Make.
